# Inform a VS Code Extension of changes in debugger state

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to write an extension for Visual Studio Code that is informed of changes in the state of the VS Code debugger? The `@vscode/debugadapter` and `vscode-debugprotocol` packages give some hints but no obvious direction.

The use-case would be that when debugging is started (say of a Python script) the extension is notified 'DebuggingStarted' and when the debug session ends a 'DebuggingEnded' notification is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug

It has a onDidStartDebugSession and onDidTerminateDebugSession.

You use it like this in your extension's activate function:

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.debug.onDidTerminateDebugSession(async (e: vscode.DebugSession) => {
    console.log("Terminated Debug Session!");

}));
```